# C# and JAVA client to MySQL server do not get along with collation at the same time

Tags: java, c#, mysql, utf-8, collation

I was playing with a test client both on C# and JAVA and wanted to execute a simple query: *select * from data;*

mysql 5.7, connector/j 5.1.39, connector/.net 6.9.9. The data table has ID and VAL columns - int and text respectively. The db schema, table and text column are using utf8 collation but strangely enough I could not make both clients to receive the query result in sync. Changing collation results in failure either in c# or java - tried utf8mb4, latin1 and more random choices.

if C# DataReader has records the JAVA ResultSet is empty or vice versa.
When C# fails it throws:
***Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset***
and inner exception:
***Expected end of data packet***. If java fails it just has an empty ResultSet

I tried to change different collation and charset/characterEncoding settings and trial and error leaded me to here:

If i use utf8 collation for the database and the following C# connection string:

***server=x.x.x.x;user=mydbuser;database=mydb;port=3306;password=mypassword;Character Set=utf8***

and this Java connection string

***jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x/mydb?user=mydbuser&password=mypassword&characterEncoding=ascii***

both apps are showing result - even when the VAL column contains utf (Cyrillic) characters the java client shows them correctly regarding the ascii parameter. if characterEncoding is set to utf8 the ResultSet is again empty.

I could not wrap my head around why this works.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831 .  In particular, please provide the `SELECT ... HEX` that it suggests.  That will help decide whether the data is already corrupted in the table.

Comment: here is the hex:
value1 76616C756531

value2 76616C756532

текст на бг D182D0B5D0BAD181D18220D0BDD0B020D0B1D0B3

Comment: OK, that is correctly stored utf8 (or utf8mb4).

Comment: Hmmm... Why do you have the hex of `value1` and ` value1`?   Is that output from 3 rows?

Comment: "ResultSet is again empty" -- Are you doing any conversions after pulling the values out?

Comment: Yes 3 rows - couldn't figure out how to format it in the comment.

No conversion at all - vanilla select and then print.

Comment: For C#, check the spelling in `Character Set=utf8`.  For jdbc, search for JDBC and Java in [_this_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll) for hints.

Comment: Rick, thanks for all your effort on this issue.
Yesterday I had to import some data (for another unrelated task) from another db and I decided to do it in my test db - it had the following line in the sql dump - _SET character_set_client = utf8_. After I finished what I had to do, I executed my test and all was ok - both c# and java were fetching the results as expected. I even removed the characterEncoding/Character Set from the connection string and it worked as expected. I assume that I messed up the db during db/table/column creation and altering the settings at some point.

Comment: Alas, there are so many knobs to tweak that when you get it right, you don't necessarily know what you did.  I have been chasing issues like this for years.  (I don't yet have the details for C# in my list.)